# Matching a simple string with regex not working?

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a large txt-file and want to extract all strings with these patterns:

```
/m/meet_the_crr
/m/commune
/m/hann_2
```

Here is what I tried:

```
import re

with open("testfile.txt", "r") as text_file:
    contents = text_file.read().replace("\n", "")

print(re.match(r'^\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', contents))
```

The result I get is a simple "None". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove `.replace("\n", "")` and use `re.findall(r'^/m/[\w-]+$', contents, re.M)`

Comment: Try putting the print statement within the `with` statement block.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I match all 3. So it seems not to be the regex.

Comment: @TAN-C-F-OK .. now use the ***real*** text you are giving the regex to work on ..after removing the `\n` .. your text is `/m/meet_the_crr/m/commune/m/hann_2` - no newlines in it  ..still matching all ?

Comment: sorry for the url mishap: it is https://regex101.com/ -your special case is here: https://regex101.com/r/PyNjiE/1  .. and it uses the Multiline-flag

Comment: @PatrickArtner I removed ^ and $ to match them after \n, but my result is still None or just nothing: "[ ]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *not* remove lineends and use the `re.MULTILINE` flag so you get multiple results from a bigger text returned:

```
# write a demo file
with open("t.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""
/m/meet_the_crr\n
/m/commune\n
/m/hann_2\n\n
# your text looks like this after .read().replace(\"\\n\",\"\")\n
/m/meet_the_crr/m/commune/m/hann_2""")
```

Program:

```
import re

regex = r"^\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"

with open("t.txt","r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

found_all =  re.findall(regex,contents,re.M) 

print(found_all)
print("-")
print(open("t.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
['/m/meet_the_crr', '/m/commune', '/m/hann_2']
```

Filecontent:

```
/m/meet_the_crr

/m/commune

/m/hann_2


# your text looks like this after .read().replace("\n","")

/m/meet_the_crr/m/commune/m/hann_2
```

This is about what  [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)  did tell you in his comment - although he suggested to use a better pattern as well: `r'^/m/[\w-]+$'`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing logically wrong with your code, and in fact your pattern will match the inputs you describe:

```
result = re.match(r'^\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', '/m/meet_the_crr')
if result:
    print(result.groups())    # this line is reached, as there is a match
```

Since you did not specify any capture groups, you will see `()` being printed to the console.  You could capture the entire input, and then it would be available, e.g.

```
result = re.match(r'(^\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$)', '/m/meet_the_crr')
if result:
    print(result.groups(1)[0])

/m/meet_the_crr
```

Comment: Is something wrong with the txt-file? I only get "[]" now.

Comment: @TAN-C-F-OK I gave my answer under the assumption that you already had the ability to read your text file line by line, and apply `match` to it.

Comment: It works, as long as I'm not putting the text-file in there.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a whole file into a variable (into memory) using `.read()`. With `.replace("\n", "")`, you re,ove all newlines in the string. The `re.match(r'^\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', contents)` tries to match the string that entirely matches the `\/m\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` pattern, and it is impossible after all the previous manipulations.

There are at least two ways out. Either remove `.replace("\n", "")` (to prevent newline removal) and use `re.findall(r'^/m/[\w-]+$', contents, re.M)` (`re.M` option will enable matching whole *lines*  rather than the whole text), or read the file line by line and use your `re.match` version to check each line for a match, and if it matches add to the final list.

Example:

```
import re
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as text_file:
    contents = text_file.read()
    print(re.findall(r'^/m/[\w-]+$', contents, re.M))
```

Or

```
import re
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        if re.match(r'/m/[\w-]+\s*$', line):
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Note I used `\w` to make the pattern somewhat shorter, but if you are working in Python 3 and only want to match ASCII letters and digits, use also `re.ASCII` option.

Also, `/` is not a special char in Python regex patterns, there is no need escaping it.

Comment: I can't believe you actually gave an answer which involves something other than regex.  New year's resolution?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Python has been my primary programming language for almost a year.